# Passing parameters to scala slick query

Tags: scala, slick, scala-collections, slick-3.0

I am trying to pass a list of integers in the `IN` clause of a SQL Server JDBC query using Slick API for scala. The val `stockIdsOfInterest` is a list of integers that I want to pass in the `IN` clause. Here is my query:

```
val stockIdsOfInterest =  gandalfIdToTickerMap.keys.take(2).toList // List[Int]
val ers = db.runSync(sql"""
        SELECT
          a.AttachmentID,
          r.stock_id,
        FROM
          Attachment as a
        JOIN
          research r ON r.id = a.research_id
        WHERE
          r.stock_id in (${stockIdsOfInterest})  -- THIS CAUSES EXCEPTION
      """.as[(Int, String, String, Int, Array[Byte], java.sql.Date)]
      );
```

When I add the `IN` clause, the query throws exception:

```
Error:(96, 39) not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[List[Int]])slick.jdbc.SetParameter[List[Int]].
Unspecified value parameter e.
      val ers = db.runSync(sql"""
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The linked question title only covers integers, but the answer is more general.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thank you! That is super helpful.